# python - cannot use sqlite data

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

I'm having an issue where I can print subscripted data from sqlite but cannot return it or assign it to a variable. Using python3 with sqlite in Windows 10.

```
def dbFindQuestion():
question = 'red'
sql = "SELECT * FROM words WHERE English=? OR German=?"
cursor.execute(sql, [(question), (question)])
print (cursor.fetchone()[0]) #this works
return (cursor.fetchone()[0]) #this doesn't
abc = (cursor.fetchone()[0]) # this doesn't
```

Printing the first column from the words table prints 'red' which is correct
However, when I return it or set it as a variable it gives me the error:

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Why is this and how can I fix it? is it just me being stupid or is there a specific way of doing it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If your query only returns one row, the second time you call `.fetchone()` will return `None`, so `cursor.fetchone()[0]` will only work once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
result = cursor.fetchone()[0]
print (result)
return (result)
```

The 1st `fetchone()` fetched only the 1 row you need and then threw it away, so the 2nd `fetchone()` you used did not fetch anything.